Do we know of a pair of categories for which we do not know if they are equivalent?
There are many categories we obviously know to be inequivalent due to some category-theoretical invariant one has that the other doesn't (for example, $\textbf{Grp}$ has a $0$ object while $\textbf{Top}$ doesnt, so these are not equivalent). There are also many seemingly distinct categories we know to be equivalent (Stone Duality is an example).
Are there any pairs of categories for which we are unsure if they are equivalent, as they seem to share most "obvious" category theoretical invariants, and yet there does not seem to be a natural way to define an equivalence functor from one to the other?

Have a look at the homotopy hypothesis and the cobordism hypothesis.

@NaïmFavier The homotopy hypothesis I understand, and is very interesting. Cobordism one might be above my pay grade, but thanks for the reply anyway!

For a somewhat silly answer, maybe take two presentations of groups where we're not sure whether they're isomorphic groups (because of the general unsolvability of the group word problem), and then take the corresponding one-object categories?

For an even sillier answer, take two sets like $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ and consider them as discrete categories.

Those are indeed silly answers in the "spirit of the question" department, but I can one-up them: Let $C$ be the empty category, and $D$ be the category that is either empty or the one-point category, depending on wether or not the Riemann hypothesis holds. Technically this is a correct answer to my question, which I guess is the best kind of correct.
